# Convert Impress ODP Presentation to several JPG images from command line

Tags: libreoffice

I would like to use openoffice or libreoffice to convert a presentation made with Impress ( odp file, but might be powerpoint ppt, too ) to jpg images.

My point is: I have an odp presentation file, composed with 10 slides, then I would receive 10 jpeg images, one for each slide.

I tried with :

soffice --headless --convert-to jpg presentation.odp

This works perfect, but I just receive the very first slide of my presentation, not all. I do need all of them.

I don't know if there's an option to tell soffice to convert *all* the slides instead of the first one.

I know there are other ways like converting to pdf and then use IM, but I want to solve this using soffice. Im doing everything under Ubuntu Linux.

Thanks in advance.

Juan

Comment: You can still use soffice to create the pdf and convert it to jpg - all using linux. AFAIK there's no option to create multiple images from impress slides using the command line. There's only a libreoffice extension dating from 2012 to do this using the GUI.

Comment: Sure, I know I could use convert from ImageMagick, but I wanted to do it just with soffice from CLI.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Im going to reply my own answer.

To convert, massively, from .odp to images, under Linux using CLI, I'll do:

```
soffice --headless --convert-to pdf presentation.odp
```

Then:

```
convert -density 400 converted.pdf -resize 800x600 my_filename%d.jpg
```

This solution works, but it needs some improvements to make it faster and to prevent it from failing due to lack of hardware resources.

But, if your odp is not *that* big, you converted from odp/ppt/pptx/whatever to images, massively, it is scriptable, and using just CLI.